# Only the first objects i made are rendering

Tags: rendering

Hi i am pretty new to blender but i was practicing with this logo but only the first two objects i made are rendering. however everything seems to render fine in my camera preview. if somebody could look at my file and help me out i would appreciate it. file

>

[image]

[image]

File is here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06456673312295020538

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It renders fine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sspay.png

Comment: hmm maybe my computer is out of spec? i have an i5 with 6gb ram and a gtx 610.

Comment: such a simple object would not stress a system like the one you describe. But do make sure you are using updaed drivers for your card

Comment: can you edit your question and add an image of what you are getting?

Comment: i will update the drivers (because they are outdated) if it persists ill try to be more specific and add a screenshot.

Comment: actually i have core i3 but i updated drivers and problem persists

Comment: Press the / key in the numpad (or on the menu go to **View->View_Global_Local**) to exit local view.

Comment: @cegaton your a life saver. i was literally so stressed out even though im just messing around in my spare time.

Answer (score 0):

Press the / key in the numpad (or on the menu go to View->View_Global_Local) to exit local view. –  cegaton 2 hours ago